# Finding total number of interval in running stream

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have stream of incoming interval in form (start,end).(1<=start < end<=100000)
At any moment ,i want to find the number of distinct intervals.

For e.g.

```
(10,20) comes first-->No of distinct interval 1.
(50,60) comes next->No of distinct interval 2.
(5,11) comes next.->No of distinct interval 3.
(8,12) comes next.->No of distinct interval 3.(As (5,11) has merged with (10,20) and formed (5,20),so (8,12) completely falls in between (5,20),so it wont be counted).
(55,65) comes next.->No of distinct interval 4.(at this point (55,65) will merge with (50,60)).
```

How to approach this question??
Like can we make heap of intervals of Self-Balancing Interval Tree??
If yes, HOW??

Comment: Yes, if you make a search tree (doesn't matter if it's balanced, that's just a performance issue) keyed on the lower bound of the interval, you can scan for the lower bound and see whether or not your new interval overlaps an existing one.

Comment: It means that for each incomin interval ,I have to scan all the exsisting interval and check with which it overlaps? So at worst,it will take N^2.

Comment: You don't need to scan all of them - in a binary search tree, for example, you can search for the key greater or equal to the key that you have in log2(n).

Comment: What would you like to do in the following case: (1, 5), (6, 10), (2, 8) ? Would you merge all three intervals and get a count of 1? Or something different?

Comment: (1,5)  No. of interval=1,
(6,10) No. of interval=2,
(2,8) No. of interval=3,
From here after ,if we insert (3,5) it wont be counted as (1,10) will contain (3,5).

Comment: You could keep a running list of sorted L values,R value pairs sorted on L values. Find the value that is just greater than the current L value. While the R value is greater than the next L value keep merging ranges. At any point the number of distinct ranges would be the length of the list